# Execute Selenium Script with Tosca

Tags: java, selenium, tosca

I am trying to run an existing Selenium Script within Tosca. But there seems to be an issue and none of the existing articles really help me.

I used the standard tbox modules "Start Selenium Server" and "Run Selenium Scripts". In those modules I changed the path to the .jar file which I created with maven. I have written the testcases with junit 4 and used chrome webdriver to execute them. When I execute them in IntelliJ they work perfectly fine but as soon as I try to import them Tosca fails to execute. 
The code looks like this:

```
public class F {

private WebDriver driver;
private JavascriptExecutor js;
private WebDriverWait wait;


@Before
public void init(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "P:/Documents/seflx/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("url");
}

@Test
public void searchSubmission() {
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    driver.switchTo().frame("workflow_frame_1");
    WebElement initScreen = driver.findElement(By.className("loading-screen"));
    WebElement loadingScreen = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html"));
}
```

As you can see in the code, I have no main class, is this the problem? Because I read in the Tosca documentary that junit is supported.

What I expect is that within tosca the selenium jar file is executed. The current outcome I get is this:

```
 Selenium Server started successfully
 Run Selenium Scripts: startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
 Parameter name: startIndex
```

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
Parameter name: startIndex
   at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
   at Tricentis.Automation.SpecialExecutionTasks.SeleniumExecution.ExecuteSeleniumTestsSpecialExecutionTask.AnalyzeJunitTestResult(String resultMessage, String outputHtml, String projectPathToLog)
   at Tricentis.Automation.SpecialExecutionTasks.SeleniumExecution.ExecuteSeleniumTestsSpecialExecutionTask.Execute(ISpecialExecutionTaskTestAction testAction)
   at Tricentis.Automation.SpecialExecutionTasks.SeleniumExecution.ExecuteSeleniumTestsSpecialExecutionTask.ExecuteTask(ISpecialExecutionTaskTestAction testAction)
   at ᜈ.ᜀ()
   at ᜈ.ᜁ()
   at Tricentis.Automation.Execution.ItemExecutor`1.Execute()
```

[screenshot of tosca output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eprX9.png)